# Uploading chunked video file to cloudinary in flutter

Tags: flutter, cloudinary, chunking

I am trying to upload a video file thats greater than 100mb to cloudinary in chunks.

I have created a class that splits the video file and uploads each chunk.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'network.dart';

class ChunkedUploader {
  final http.Client _client;

  ChunkedUploader(this._client);

  Future<http.StreamedResponse> upload({
    String url,
    File file,
    Map<String, dynamic> body,
    int maxChunkSize,
    int uniqueId,
    Function(double) onUploadProgress,
  }) =>
      UploadRequest(
        _client,
        url: url,
        file: file,
        body: body,
        maxChunkSize: maxChunkSize,
        uniqueId: uniqueId,
        onUploadProgress: onUploadProgress,
      ).upload();
}

class UploadRequest {
  final http.Client client;
  final String url;
  final File file;
  final Map<String, dynamic> body;
  final int uniqueId;
  final Function(double) onUploadProgress;
  int _fileSize;
  int _maxChunkSize;

  UploadRequest(
    this.client, {
    this.url,
    this.file,
    this.body,
    this.uniqueId,
    this.onUploadProgress,
    int maxChunkSize,
  }) {
    _fileSize = file.lengthSync();
    _maxChunkSize = min(_fileSize, maxChunkSize ?? _fileSize);
  }

  Future<http.StreamedResponse> upload() async {

    http.StreamedResponse finalResponse;

    for (int i = 0; i < _chunksCount; i++) {
      final start = _getChunkStart(i);
      final end = _getChunkEnd(i);
      final chunkStream = _getChunkStream(start, end);
      

      MultipartRequest request = MultipartRequest(
        "POST",
        Uri.parse(url),
        onProgress: (int bytes, int total) {
          _updateProgress(i, bytes, total);
        },
      );

      //Add the headers
      request.headers.addAll(_getHeaders(start, end));

      //Add the body
      request.fields.addAll(body);

      //Get the file
      http.MultipartFile multipartFile =
          http.MultipartFile("file", chunkStream, end - start);
      request.files.add(multipartFile);

      //Send the file
      http.StreamedResponse response =
          await client.send(request).catchError((error) {
        throw error;
      });

      print(response);
      finalResponse = response;
    }
    return finalResponse;
  }

  Stream<List<int>> _getChunkStream(int start, int end) =>
      file.openRead(start, end);

  // Updating total upload progress
  _updateProgress(int chunkIndex, int chunkCurrent, int chunkTotal) {
    int totalUploadedSize = (chunkIndex * _maxChunkSize) + chunkCurrent;
    double totalUploadProgress = (totalUploadedSize / _fileSize) * 100;
    this.onUploadProgress?.call(totalUploadProgress);
  }

  // Returning start byte offset of current chunk
  int _getChunkStart(int chunkIndex) => chunkIndex * _maxChunkSize;

  // Returning end byte offset of current chunk
  int _getChunkEnd(int chunkIndex) =>
      min((chunkIndex + 1) * _maxChunkSize, _fileSize);

  // Returning a header map object containing Content-Range
  // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233#section-2
  Map<String, String> _getHeaders(int start, int end) => {
        'X-Unique-Upload-Id': "$uniqueId",
        'Content-Range': 'bytes $start-${end - 1}/$_fileSize',
      };

  // Returning chunks count based on file size and maximum chunk size
  int get _chunksCount => (_fileSize / _maxChunkSize).ceil();
}
```

When making the request i am getting a response of

```
Status code - 500
Body - {
    “error” : {
        “message” : "General Error”
    }
}
```

I have been in touch with cloudinary and they have found the request and said that it is failing with the error: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hello  @Luke Chase, Are you able divide video into small chunks please help how to do it